# Simple GET request with AngularJS and PHP, expected JSON but got copy of the php file returned

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to figure out AngularJS with PHP as backend.
The purpose here is to generate a JSON file from a mysql database, but in return my data variable is a string containing literally the code from my php file.

Here is the code:

*The angular controller:*

```
(function (){
"use strict";

var module = angular.module("App");

var CountryController = function ($scope, $http, $log) {

    $scope.countries = null;

    $http.get('php/get_countries.php')
    .success(function(data){
            $log.info("data= " + data);
        $scope.countries = data;
    });
};

module.controller("CountryController", CountryController);
}());
```

*The php file:*

```
<?php

$db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','db_test');

if($db->connect_errno > 0) {
    die('Unable to connect to database[' .$db->connect_error. ']');
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `country`";


if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' .$db->error. ']');
}

$arr = array();
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $item = array();
        $item['id'] = $row['country_id'];
        $item['name'] = $row['country_name'];
        $arr[] = $item;
    }
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

The log shows me a copy of the code from the php file.
I compared my code with other examples online with the same purpose, and I can't find anyone who runs into the same problem.
Also I ran the php code in my browser, which returns the correct JSON code. Only when I try to use it in my angular app, I get the php code returned as a string.

Comment: This sounds like a web server configuration problem. What are you using? Apache or IIS?

Comment: php is not being parsed

Comment: If you visit `http://www.example.com/php/get_countries.php`, what do you get? (Replace example.com with your actual domain name, of course.)

Comment: Mathew and Brian mentioned that this could be a server configuration issue. Make sure whatever web server you have running is setup to handle .php files. They need to be executed and not just returned.

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody ! It was indeed the fact that my IDE could not handle php files. I copied my working folder to my xampp folder, and ran it from there. Everything worked